# Dynamically enabling a check list based on radio button (yes/no) response in a form

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I am attempting to make a list of check boxes disabled unless the user explicitly states that the said list applies to the situation. I have a form with nested tables, menus, data entry, and problems found list. Essentially, for better or worse, multiple tables on one form. This is beginning to cause me grief as the functions of this form are growing exponentially. For simplicity's sake, I am focusing on the "repairs to be made" table.

I have a checklist of various things to be repaired that is proceeded by a Yes or No question for the user. Instead of running JavaScript validation on each possible repair option, I want to disable the entire list if no repairs are necessary, (i.e. "does it need any repairs?", "No", checklist disabled). I am not using CSS as I have little to no experience in web form programming and have based my code on pre-existing code that did not include CSS.

My example will use generic names and variables, and is intended to illustrate that these forms are passed through several stages before they are considered completed, thus the PHP echo variables.

```
<?php
 $previous_response_yes=='';
 $previous_response_no=='';
 if ($row_GetData[Question] == "1")
 {
  $previous_response_yes="checked";
 }
 else
 {
  $previous_response_no="checked";
 }
?>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2" align="center">
   Are there any damaged components?
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<!-- this variable is used in java script verification elsewhere -->
  <td>
   Yes: <input type="radio" name="question" value="1" id="yes" <?php echo $previous_response_yes; ?> />
  </td>
  <td>
   No: <input type="radio" name="question" value="0" id="no" <?php echo $previous_response_no; ?> />
  </td>
 </tr>
<!-- various checklist items, example as follows... -->
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="hidden" name="damaged_part" value="0" />
   <input type="checkbox" name="damaged_part" value="1" id="damaged_part" <?php echo $damaged_part1 <!-- code for determining if = "checked" or not omitted --> ; ?> />
  </td>
  <td>
   Damaged Part
  </td>
 </tr>
<!-- lists continues on for some time -->
</table>
```

Now I assume that I need an "onclick" or "oncheck" qualifier in either the Yes radio button, No radio button, or both to toggle back and forth between disabling and enabling the checklist that follows. I have found very similar ideas, but none have worked in my recreation of them. Essentially, what I want is something to the extent of

```
while <input type="radio" name="question" value="0" id="no" <?php echo $previous_response_no; ?> /> is checked
following checklist disabled="disabled"
```

Comment: I think you might be aware of this, but for the avoidance of doubt: Java is not the same as JavaScript. I've fixed the reference to Java in your question.

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know, using tables for layout is not the most optimal method.  And, the effect that you are seeking can be fully implemented using CSS.  Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X93Vj/.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <label>Damaged components?</label> <input type = "checkbox" id = "damaged" />
    <div class = "componentsList">
        <label><input type = "checkbox" id = "electric">Electric</label>
        <label><input type = "checkbox" id = "mechanical">Mechanical</label>
    </div>
    <p>Sample paragraph</p>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
form > label, 
form > input[type = "checkbox"] {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

form > .componentsList {
    margin: 5px 0 0 20px;
}

form > .componentsList > label {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}

form > input[type = "checkbox"]:not(:checked) + .componentsList {
    display: none;
}

form > input[type = "checkbox"]:checked + .componentsList {
    display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fixes. Both disable and uncheck boxes if No is chosen and check for No being checked on load.

Here's a fix that will do things using plain JavaScript (jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/k34zR/9/ -- this doesn't seem to work in jsfiddle, but works in an html document) :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var yesBox = document.getElementById('yes'),
        noBox = document.getElementById('no'),
        checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

    if (noBox.checked) {
        for (var i in checkboxes) {
            if (checkboxes.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                checkboxes[i].disabled = true;
            }
        };
    }
    yesBox.addEventListener('click', function () {
        for (var i in checkboxes) {
            if (checkboxes.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                checkboxes[i].disabled = false;
            }
        };
    });
    noBox.addEventListener('click', function () {
        for (var i in checkboxes) {
            if (checkboxes.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                checkboxes[i].disabled = true;
                checkboxes[i].checked = false;
            }
        };
    });

});
```

Or if you're using jQuery (jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/k34zR/10/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $radios = $('input[type=radio]'),
        $boxes = $('input[type=checkbox]');

    if ($('#no').is('checked')) {
        $boxes.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }

    $radios.on('click', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.attr('id') == "no") {
            $boxes.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $boxes.attr('checked', false);
        } else {
            $boxes.removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```